# How to get protocol behind cloudfront / load balancer with nodejs?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, nginx, amazon-cloudfront, amazon-elb

I'd like to redirect all users using http protocol to https. However I'm behind an aws cloudfront + load balancer.

How can I determine the original client protocol of the request in nodejs?

How can I redirect the user? Is it the right way to use node or are there other possibilities with the load balancer / cloudfront?

Answer (score 3):

For the load balancer, your ELB will set a [`X-Forwarded-Proto`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/classic/x-forwarded-headers.html#x-forwarded-proto) header. Use it to redirect.

As to configure your cloud front instance, go the instance behaviours, and edit your behaviours so that it requires connection over HTTPS.

Comment: `X-Forwarded-Proto` is set to the protocol between CloudFront and the balancer.  `Cloudfront-Forwarded-Proto` is set to the protocol between the browser and CloudFront.  As this answer implies, CloudFront can be configured to forcefully redirect http to https automatically.